# Nock headers - Error: Nock: No match for request

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, nock

Here's my example code for some reason Nock is failing for me as it can't match the URL when headers are added, when commenting the code like below the test passes. I can't figure out why nock doesn't understand the headers as the doc says to do this which i've done that: reqheaders: { 'authorization' : 'Basic Auth' }

Hoping someone might able to pick up something odd i'm doing.

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function postAPI(params) {
    let response1 = '';
    try {
        response1 =  await axios.post('http://someurl/test2', params);
        
    } catch(error) {
        throw error;
    }

    try {
        console.log("Im here", response1.data.sample)
    const response = await axios.get('http://testurl/testing', {
        // headers: {
        //   'authorization' : 'Basic Auth' //+ response1.data.sample 
        // }
       });
       return response.data;
    
    } catch(err) {
            console.log("Error", err)
    }
}

exports.postAPI = postAPI;
```

Test

```
it('make an api call - POST', async () => {

      nock('http://someurl')
      .persist()
      .defaultReplyHeaders({
        'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
        'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true' 
      })
        .post('/test2')
        .reply(200, {
                sample : 'test2'     
  });

    const test = nock('http://testurl', {
    //  reqheaders: {
    //    'authorization' : 'Basic Auth'
    //  }
    })
    .defaultReplyHeaders({
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true'
    })
      .get('/testing')
      .reply(200, { data : 'test' });

      const response = await postAPI();
      console.log("XXXX", response)
      expect(response.data).toEqual("test");
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling debug to see why Nock isn't matching your request? https://github.com/nock/nock#debugging

Comment: Having difficulty with it on the work code for some reason its not hitting the URL and get a response of undefined. Where as at home was getting somewhere, other then the auth header issues. Going to try axios mock instead, and see if that works better for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reqheaders must match what you pass in axios requst headers.

```
reqheaders: {
    'authorization' : 'Basic Auth test2'
}
```

when you concatenate authorization header in main function remember to add a space between Auth and response1.data.sample :)

```
'authorization' : 'Basic Auth ' + response1.data.sample
```

I tried your code and it works.
Full test:

```
const nock = require('nock');
const { postAPI } = require('./index');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('postapi', () => {
    it('make an api call - POST', async () => {

        nock('http://someurl')
        .defaultReplyHeaders({
          'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
          'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true' 
        })
          .post('/test2')
          .reply(200, {
                  sample : 'test2'     
        });
    
        nock('http://testurl', {
            reqheaders: {
            'authorization' : 'Basic Auth test2'
            }
        })
        .defaultReplyHeaders({
            'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
            'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true'
        })
        .get('/testing')
        .reply(200, { data : 'test' });
    
        const response = await postAPI();
        console.log("XXXX", response)
        expect(response.data).to.be.eql("test");
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, didn’t spot that space  have used nock for some other stuff but its good to know where I was going wrong.